# Excaption not including

Tags: python

I have a file at /location/data.txt . In this file I have entry like :

> aaa:xxx:abc.com:1857:xxx1:rel5t2:y
>
> ifa:yyy:xyz.com:1858:yyy1:rel5t2:y

I want to access 'aaa' from my code either I mention aaa while giving the input in caps or small after running my python code it should return me aaa is the right item 
But here I want to include one exception that if I give the input with -mc suffix (aaa-mc) either in small latters or in caps it should ignore the -mc.
Below is the my code and output as well which I am getting now.

def pITEMName():

```
    global ITEMList,fITEMList
    pITEMList = []
    fITEMList = []
    ITEMList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of ITEMS : ')).upper().strip()
    items = ITEMList.split("|")
    count = len(items)
    print  'Total Distint ITEM Count : ',  count
    pipelst = [i.split('-mc')[0] for i in ITEMList.split('|')]
    filepath = '/location/data.txt'
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    for lns in f:
            split_pipe = lns.split(':', 1)
            if split_pipe[0] in pipelst:
                    index = pipelst.index(split_pipe[0])
                    pITEMList=split_pipe[0]+"|"
                    fITEMList.append(pITEMList)
                    del pipelst[index]
    for lns in pipelst:
        print bcolors.red + lns,' is wrong ITEM Name' + bcolors.ENDC
    f.close()
```

When I execute above code it prompts me like :

> Enter pipe separated list of ITEMS :

And if I provide the list like :

> Enter pipe separated list of ITEMS : aaa-mc|ifa

it gives me the result as :

> Total Distint item Count :  2
>
> AAA-MC  is wrong item Name
>
> items Belonging to other :
>
> Other center :
>
> item Count From Other center =  0
>
> items Belonging to Current Centers :
>
> Active items in US1 :
>
> ^IFA$
>
> Active items in  US2 :
>
> ^AAA$
>
> Ignored item Count From Current center =  0
>
> You Have Entered itemList belonging to this center as: ^IFA$|^AAA$
>
> Active item Count :  2
>
> Do You Want To Continue [YES|Y|NO|N] :

As you must be see in above result aaa is coming as valid count (active item count : 2) because its available in /location/data.txt file. but also its coming as AAA-MC is wrong item name (2nd line from above result). I want '-mc or -MC' to ignore with any item present or non present in /location/data.txt file.

Please let me know what's wrong with my above code to achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are constructing `ITEMList` is by reading in a string, capitalizing it (with `upper()`), and stripping all whitespace.  Therefore, something like `'aaa-mc'` is being converted to `'AAA-MC'`.  You're later splitting this uppercase string on the token '-mc', which is impossible for it to contain, so.

I'd reccommed either replacing `upper()` with `lower()` when you are reading your string in, or doing a hard replace on the types of `'-mc'`, so instead of

```
i.split('-mc')[0]
```

try using

```
i.replace('-mc','').replace('-MC','')
```

in your list comprension.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're having is that your code expects the `"-mc"` suffix to appear in lowercase, but you're calling the `upper()` method on the input string, resulting in text that is all upper case. You need to change one of those so that they match (it doesn't really matter which one).

Either replace the `upper()` call with `lower()`, or replace the string `"-mc"` with `"-MC"`, and your code should work better (I'm not certain I understand all of it, so there may be other issues).